# Printing the CBCharacteristic._handle value in Swift

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, mirror

I have some wireshark logs which show characteristic read writes by handle value. I wanted to dump a map of each characteristic handle value into it's GUID representation.

I've tried using `Mirror(reflecting: characteristic)` but the returned Mirror instance's children collection is empty (which is also weird since the characteristic has a bunch of public/private properties).

Unless I am misunderstanding what reflection is in Swift, I don't see what I am doing wrong.
Suggestions? I really don't care about using reflection vs a different method (although one of my goals is to understand that part too).

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clean, but you can invoke the private Objective-C accessor using a selector:

```swift
let res = characteristic.perform(Selector(("handle")));
let handle = res!.takeUnretainedValue() as! NSNumber;
print(handle);
```

Comment: Thank you, it might not be the same value that goes on the wire but worth a check. It didn't have to be clean as it's just for dumping/logging purposes! Grazie